# Missing CMake variable when compiling with OpenSSL

Tags: linux, compilation, cmake

I am trying to compile a servermod on Debian using CMake. Every required packages seems do be installed. If I start compiling I get this error:

```
    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
    Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
    OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)

    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)

    OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
```

and I have absolutely no clue how to fix it. Where does it has to be set?

Comment: Have you installed OpenSSL?

Comment: yes sure openssl is installed

Comment: Can you show the makefile?

Comment: can you explain? Sorry but i am no expert, just downloaded the mod following steps given in a tutorial.

Comment: see: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1710628.html

Comment: There's nothing in that link about OpenSSL.  Have you installed the devel version of OpenSSL?  Something like `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: Obviously, CMake cannot file openssl. What openSSl package have you installed? Also the dev packages? Can you give us some lines for the configure output whether they indicate that OpenSSL is found? And maybe you can have a look in CMakeFiles/CMakeErrors.log where details of the errors are stored.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to install the development kit of openssl.

```
apt install libssl-dev
```

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.